# SSIS Visual Studio 2019 for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssis

The question is can I use Visual Studio 2019 with the most current SSIS to create SSIS packages for SQL Server 2008? Or do I need to download an earlier version of Visual Studio?

I do not have access yet to execute on the server I am waiting for this and just doing some research to get tools ready in the mean time. So I have not tried anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio 2019.

This is the link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Says that you can't.

> Supported SQL versions
>
> Integration Services packages  SQL Server 2012 - SQL Server 2019

Comment: i currently have that.  the problem is i need ssis support for sql server 2008?

Comment: I had the same problem time ago. I realized that I ended changing my SQL server version to 2014. If you can't do the same, maybe your best shot is to install an early version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SSIS 2008 is too old. Additionally, SQL Server 2008, and its SSIS, are out of support. I strongly suggest upgrading your SSIS to a later and supported version.

VS2019 supports SSIS development for the following SSIS versions:

- 2012
- 2014
- 2016
- 2017
- 2019

**-- UPDATE --**

> can sql server2008 use ssis later than 2008? this is what i was trying
> to establish

No, SQL Server version and SSIS version are one and the same.

**-- UPDATE #2 --**

BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio) can be found after installing the full version of SQL server 2008.

Check it out here: [Creating a SSIS package in VS 2008](http://www.techbubbles.com/sql-server/creating-a-ssis-package-in-vs-2008/)

Comment: unfortunately i have no control over the sql server being 2008.  can sql server2008 use ssis later than 2008?  this is what i was trying to establish.  i can an install what ever i need on my desktop.  the problem is what will work when i deploy it to 2008 server

Comment: @eleethesontai, I updated the answer. Check it out.

Comment: ok this is what I thought.  So the new question is what is the lastest version of visual studio that will still allow me to make ssis packages for sql server 2008?

Comment: thank you this is what i was afraid of.  from what i gather during research, to get bids i need to install full version of 2008 server on my development machine? is that correct?  doesn't sql server require a license?

Comment: SQL Server Development edition is free. And you don't need to install the entire SQL Server on a dev. Machine, just needed components.

Comment: oh thank you that's a relief, I thought I was sol for a minute lol.  do you happen to know of a good link of which components I will need with active links if possible.  I tried find some and lots of dead links cuz its older than my grandma lol.  I wish they would upgrade me but they won't :(

Comment: https://sqljoe.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/configuring-bids-2008-2008-r2-and-visual-studio-2008-to-work-with-database-business-intelligence-projects-and-team-foundation-server-tfs/

Comment: you will have the option to install BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio) under the Client Tools section in your installation.

Comment: thank you I will try this at work today.  Do you know if visual studio 2008 had a community edition, and if so will it work for this?  If I have to get a license it will add months of red tape to this process ugh :(.